How to cross-reference figures and tables with a custom link text?
Basically, instead of @ref(fig:Date-vs-Duration) I would like to use something like [click here](\@ref(fig:Date-vs-Duration)) because /ref only generates numerical links and I want more text to be clickable.
There is this  previous question and answer but I fail to see how it adds any customized text. It also doesn't work on my end.
What I tried: \hypertarget{fig:yourfigure}{}

If you are willing to use quarto, there is the option of custom floats.
